# How to get the background attribute from the nodes of treemap in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

A part of my code which draws the d3 treemap nodes is given below:

```
var node = svg.datum(data).selectAll(".tree_rect")
      .data(treemap.nodes)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "tree_rect")
        .call(position)
        .style("background", function(d) { return d.children ? null:color_scale(d.Percentage, d['Planned Date'], d['Actual Date']); })
       .on("mousemove", mousemove)
       .on("mouseout", mouseout)
```

Now, how can I get the color of that particular node, so that I could reuse it for a different function.

Answer (score 1):

May be by giving each node an id something like this:

```
var node = svg.datum(data).selectAll(".tree_rect")
      .data(treemap.nodes)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "tree_rect")
      .attr("id", function(d) {/*SOME ID FOR THE NODE*/ return d.id;})
      ..
```

later on get the node's color using its id something like below:

```
var color = d3.select("#" ID)
              .style("background")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your solution... But giving ID's will not solve my problem... I have specified a function for coloring each node. So if I could get the colors I could change the text colors according to it. @Cyril

Comment: how about storing the background colors inside the data itself..that should solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using the `.style` attribute.

Example

```
var t = node.append("text")
                .style("color", function(d){ //your function definition for color here//});
```